# "make someone likely to do"?

Tags: grammar, structure

In grammar rule, the verb "make" follow infinitive without "to": for example my teacher made me study hard.
But I found a below sentence.

> The act of being heavily committed makes an executive likely to miss certain sighs.

I am confusing because I think the phrase seems infinitive with "to" for me.

Or the phrase "likely to do" works as an adjective, here?

Comment: I don't believe your grammar rule exists: *I was made* ***to*** *clean the floor*. Can you provide a link to the rule you're thinking of? It's possible there is a misinterpretation.

Comment: Cambridge dictionary: Make meaning ‘force to do’
We can use make meaning ‘force someone (to do something)’. In the active voice, we use it with an infinitive without to:

The boss made me work an extra day.

Not: The boss made me to work …

However, in the passive voice, we must use an infinitive with to:

The people were made to wait outside while the committee reached its decision.

Comment: So, what you're saying is that *to* never immediately follows *make* in an active-voice construction. How about *I made to take a step forward when I noticed the tripwire*? No, because you're talking about the meaning of *forced* specifically. The reason for that is because it's used transitively. Make has to be followed by an object: *I made (him / her / them / it) do something.* In your example sentence, *to* does not come immediately after *make*. It's not *makes* ***to*** *an executive*.

Comment: So, I mean that the quoted sentence, "the act of being heavily committed makes an executive "to" miss certain sighs", without likely would be the wrong sentence, I think. because the "to" followed the verb make.

Comment: No, the sentence is fine. As I said, it is not *makes* ***to*** *an executive*. *To* comes after *makes*, but not immediately after it. It doesn't matter if it comes after it *at some point* in the rest of the sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes to your last question: "likely to miss ..." works as an adjective in this sentence.

The grammar of the sentence:

> "The act of being heavily committed makes an executive likely to miss
>   certain sig**n**s."

is similar to the grammar in

> The act of being heavily committed makes an executive careless.

The rule about "make" with the bare infinitive of a *verb* (meaning to cause [someone] to do [something]) doesn't apply to this situation because the whole phrase "likely to miss certain sig**n**s" is functionally an adjective in the sentence (not a verb).